# Angular - Problems dealing with formArrayName

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am building an Angular library, that the ideal functionality will be giving access to a selector that has two inputs.

- a reactive form (with the data)
- an object literal (with the info about what properties of my data should get an editable input field)

and then the library automatically will generate the html.

**The actual question**, in the project using the library (let's call it `tester`) I have defined the reactive form. This form gets passed in the library. The problems occur when handling the array.

[image]

In the library, I first access first the desired group:
`[formGroup]="myForm.options.form.controls.allFriends"`(seems to work)

and then the array:
`[formArrayName]="myForm.options.form.controls.allFriends.controls.friends"` (throws the following error)

[image]

What also strikes as odd is, that a parent component has already `[formGroup]="myForm.options.form"` but I can not use `formGroupName` where I use `formGroup` (see a couple of lines above) because I get an error about not having a `formGroup`.

It is a bit complex so if you do not get what I am trying to do please ask for clarifications.

Comment: As I don't see the whole html implementation I can not recreate it. 
But this link was very helpfull for me while creating nested forms in Angular with the reactive approach.  https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName#how-to-use) state, a `formArrayName` directive only needs the 'name' of the `formArray` control and not the entire form-path leading to that form control as long as your parent form is defined properly in your template.

Here, you seem to be specifying the entire formArray object to that directive, `[formArrayName]="expandedRowForm.options.form.controls.allFriends.controls.friends"`. Also, not sure what `expandedRowForm` object is by the way. You are referring to `myForm` object in the assignment that worked for you, `[formGroup]="myForm.options.form.controls.allFriends"`.

Check if that helps.

Comment: expandedRowForm is a typo. Just corrected it. Let me try your suggestion and get back at you